# Program compiles, but stops when I attempt to run

Tags: c, debugging, xdebug

I have written the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

struct address
{
char street[18];
char city[13];
char state[7];
char zip[5];
};
struct student
{
char first_name[7];
char initial;
char last_name[9];
struct address add;
int age;
double gpa;
};

void readData(struct student students[], int *n);
void print(struct student students[], int n);
void bestGPA(struct student students[], int n);
double averageGPA(struct student students[], int n);
void printAboveGPA(struct student students[], int n, double avg);
void youngestStudent(struct student students[], int n, double avg);
void sort(struct student students[], int n);

int main()
{
struct student students[20];
int n=0;

readData(students, &n);

print(students, n);

bestGPA(students, n);

double avg = averageGPA(students, n);
printf("Average GPA is: %.2lf\n", avg);

printAboveGPA(students, n, avg);

youngestStudent(students, n, avg);

sort(students, n);

printf("\nNow sorted based on GPA: \n");
print(students, n);

return 0;

}


void readData(struct student students[], int *d)
{
int n = 0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("Students.dat", "r");

if(fp == NULL) {
printf("Students.dat file not found.\n");
exit(1);
}

else
{
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %c %s",
students[n].first_name,
&students[n].initial,
students[n].last_name) == 3)
{

char add1[10], add2[10], add3[10];
fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", add1, add2, add3);

strcpy(students[n].add.street, add1);
strcat(students[n].add.street, " ");
strcat(students[n].add.street, add2);
strcat(students[n].add.street, " ");
strcat(students[n].add.street, add3);

fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d %lf", students[n].add.city, students[n].add.state, students[n].add.zip,&students[n].age, &students[n].gpa);

n++;
}
}

*d = n;
}

void print(struct student students[], int n)
{
int i;
for( i=0; i<n; i++)
{
printf("%s %c %s %s %s %s %s %d %.2lf\n"
, students[i].first_name
, students[i].initial
, students[i].last_name
,students[i].add.street
,students[i].add.city
,students[i].add.state
,students[i].add.zip
,students[i].age
,students[i].gpa);
}
}

void bestGPA(struct student students[], int n)
{
struct student s = students[0];

int bestGPAIndex = 0;
int i;
for( i=1; i<n; i++)
{
if(students[bestGPAIndex].gpa < students[i].gpa)
{
bestGPAIndex = i;
}
}

printf("\n\nThe student with best GPA is: %c %s %s\n\n", students[bestGPAIndex].initial, students[bestGPAIndex].first_name,students[bestGPAIndex].last_name);
}

double averageGPA(struct student students[], int n)
{
int i;

double total;
double avg;

for( i=0; i<n; i++)
{
total += students[i].gpa;
}

avg = total/n;

return avg;
}

void printAboveGPA(struct student students[], int n, double avg)
{
int i;
printf("\nStudents with GPA more than average: \n");

for( i=0; i<n; i++)
{
if(students[i].gpa > avg)
{
printf("%c %s %s\n", students[i].initial, students[i].first_name, students[i].last_name);
}
}
}

void youngestStudent(struct student students[], int n, double avg)
{
int i;
printf("\nYoungest student with GPA less than average: ");

int youngestStudentIndex=students[0].age;
int isFound = 0;



for( i=0; i<n; i++)
{
if(students[i].gpa < avg)
{
if(!isFound)
{
isFound = 1;
youngestStudentIndex = i;
}

if(students[youngestStudentIndex].age >= students[i].age)
{
youngestStudentIndex = i;
}

}
}

if(isFound)
printf("%c %s %s\n\n", students[youngestStudentIndex].initial, students[youngestStudentIndex].first_name, students[youngestStudentIndex].last_name);
else
printf("Not found !!\n\n");
}

void sort(struct student students[], int n)
{
int i,j;
for (i = 0 ; i < ( n - 1 ); i++)
{
for (j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
{
if (students[j].gpa > students[j+1].gpa) 
{
struct student s = students[j];
students[j] = students[j+1];
students[j+1] = s;
}
}
}
}
```

All I get is that students.exe has stopped working when I go to run.  Trying to debug in visual studio gives the message "Unhandled exception at 0x76F3D062 (ntdll.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x7504006D."  Honestly though, I'm not really sure what that means.  I'm using CodeLite as the IDE to develop the program.  Any help or hint at where I might have an issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But would that cause the program to stop working?  Also, couldn't I just make the street array bigger?  Doing so does not fix the problem.

Comment: What does your input file (Students.dat) look like... perhaps a snippet of it.  Does your program always die when reading a specific line in that file????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your street array is only 18 bytes. you put up to 30 bytes in it depending on the data you read 3 times 9 bytes from add1,add2 and add3, 2 spaces and the terminating 0 - 
assuming your data elements fit the 9 bytes of your arrays the last one is need for 0